# Event not triggering on a content scripts Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a [`content scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) Chrome extension. I've dynamically added a button to a webpage, however the event listener on this button won't trigger.

Here is `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
      }
  ]
}
```

This is `script.js`:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
var button = $('<input id="btn" type="button"/>');
$("body").append(button);  

$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
});
```

The button is added to the page and background changes to yellow, but it doesn't change to red when clicking button.

Comment: Is there any button exists with same id `#btn` on the main page ?

Comment: that should work. You could try a delegate:- `$("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){`

Comment: Working for me i have used same code... definitely problem is with the button id

Comment: If JavaScript is blocked then how `background changes to yellow`?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when dev tools is open, but it works when I close it.

Answer (score 2):

If the suspected issue is with the button ID - note that you don't *need* the ID at all.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
var button = $('<input id="btn" type="button"/>');
$("body").append(button);  

button.on("click", function(){ // Notice you don't need to search for it again!
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
});
```

However, in this case you'll need to keep the `button` variable to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

This unique id may help you ;)

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
uniqueId = 'btn' + Date.now();
var button = $('<input id="' + uniqueId + '" type="button"/>');
$("body").append(button);

$("#" + uniqueId).on("click", function(){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```